# Limit reputation from questions to 100 top-rated questions

Tags: feature-request, reputation

There have been a few posts here complaining about some users having high reputation that is earned from asking a very large number of mediocre questions and few, if any, answers.  I sympathize with these complaints and propose the following solution:

Limit a user's reputation derived from asking questions to the user's 100 top-rated questions.  This encourages new users to ask questions to quickly amass a moderate amount of reputation.  To continue to earn reputation after the first 100 questions, the user will have to ask higher-quality questions.  For example, if a user has already asked 100 questions with one upvote each, the user will have to ask a two-upvote question to further increase reputation.

This way, the users with very high reputation will have to either (1) answer questions or (2) ask 100 **really good** questions.

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow. Since this question has a downvote, let me link you to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work) which explains what downvotes mean on Meta.

Comment: @waiwai933 Thanks for the tip.  I guess others don't like my idea...

Comment: Nope. We don't :)

Comment: Yeah, not gonna vote it down now, but the intention is good. Good enough to use as pavement... :)

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't this lead to "rich get richer" and "blockbuster" syndrome?

It might also lead to some odd and possibly pathological behaviors, since all your old posts become your most valuable reputation generators -- and posting something new would be heavily disincentivized.

At first glance, it seems like there is a lot of risk and downside here.

Comment: Thanks for a substantive response instead of just a downvote.  I think the primary incentive in asking questions is to get answers -- not to build reputation.  When I ask a question, I primarily want a solution so I can get back to work.  Questions for reputation are good for new users to get involved and feel part of the community, but I don't think there is an ongoing need to get reputation for questions.  Plus, there is still incentive to ask good questions.

Comment: Good catch Jeff (Atwood), the top voted questions are, IIRC, staggeringly high rated.